# Getting string array size

Tags: java

In my app I'm sending a String array to a db on my server.

I want to check before I send the String array to my server that the array size is not bigger than 1MB.

How can I check my array size?

Comment: How are you sending it? What serialization have you used?

Comment: in which language php or java?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
String entireArray = Arrays.toString(arrayOfStrings); // If you don't want to use this method, you can make your own
int finalSizeInBytes = entireArray.length() * 2; //Each character is 2B

double finalSizeInMB = (double)finalSizeInBytes/(1024*1024); //convert to B to MB
if(finalSizeInMB > 1) {
    //More than 1MB
} else {
    //Less than 1MB
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since you are using JSON to send your data to the server, you should change that line

```
String entireArray = Arrays.toString(arrayOfStrings);
```

To

```
String entireArray = /* Whatever you use to get a JSON representation of the array */;
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

This code should work with all charsets:

```
int finalSizeInBytes = yourString.getBytes().length;

double finalSizeInMB = (double)finalSizeInBytes/(1024*1024); //convert to B to MB
if(finalSizeInMB > 1) {
    //More than 1MB
} else {
    //Less than 1MB
}
```

With

```
yourString = "汉字/漢字";
```

I get

```
finalSizeInBytes = 13
```

With the previous method i get `10` (string length is `5`, `5*2 = 10`), which is wrong, `13` is the right value.

Comment: What about the array?

Comment: My point is this is not the right way to go about it. You're not going to send the memory that Java uses to store the array.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis From the OP question i understood that he wants to know if the data that is being sent is > 1M, so the memory used by java doesn't matter here, it matters the size of what he sends

Comment: @BackSlash Exactly, so until OP tells us how they send the data, there can be no answer.

Comment: @dasdasd So replace `entireArray` with your JSON string

Comment: @dasdasd Then you need to calculate the length of the JSON string.

Comment: Does this answer still apply if the data is not in UTF-8?  I don't know how precise you need to be but we do some things in Japanese and other glyph based languages here and this could be an issue

Comment: @RobertBeltran Probably not. AFAIK characters size is different between charsets, so you have to know how many bytes a character takes. If you know this information, it will work, because instead of `entireArray.length() * 2` you'll write `entireArray.length() * bytesPerCharacter`. If you don't know how many bytes your charset takes for a single character you can't calculate what it's size will be.

Comment: @RobertBeltran I updated the answer, the new code should work with all charsets. See _Update 2_